# Javascript function doesn't change the color of the button back after spamming the button

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating Django-RestFramework app, but it's not that important. In one of my templates i've created keyboard (bootstrap buttons) because User there has to type specific letters. I also created JS function that listens for keyboard clicks and then flashes corresponding button on the screen. After 0.2s button's color gets back to original state, but im getting some kind of error:
When I hold the button, color is changing and then it's not going back into original state. Any advices?

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="boxes-row">
    {% for i in '12345' %}
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        {% for letter in word.word %}
        <div class="word-box">
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="keyboard">
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonQ">Q</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonW">W</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonE">E</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonR">R</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonT">T</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonY">Y</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonU">U</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonI">I</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonO">O</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg top" id="buttonP">P</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-1">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonA">A</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonS">S</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonD">D</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonF">F</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonG">G</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonH">H</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonJ">J</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonK">K</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg mid" id="buttonL">L</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-1">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonBackspace">&nbsp;&nbsp;⌫&nbsp;&nbsp</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonZ">Z</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonX">X</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonC">C</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonV">V</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonB">B</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonN">N</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonM">M</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg down" id="buttonEnter">Enter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

script.js:

```
// Get references to keyboard buttons
const buttonMap = {
    'Q': document.getElementById('buttonQ'),
    'W': document.getElementById('buttonW'),
    'E': document.getElementById('buttonE'),
    'R': document.getElementById('buttonR'),
    'T': document.getElementById('buttonT'),
    'Y': document.getElementById('buttonY'),
    'U': document.getElementById('buttonU'),
    'I': document.getElementById('buttonI'),
    'O': document.getElementById('buttonO'),
    'P': document.getElementById('buttonP'),
    'A': document.getElementById('buttonA'),
    'S': document.getElementById('buttonS'),
    'D': document.getElementById('buttonD'),
    'F': document.getElementById('buttonF'),
    'G': document.getElementById('buttonG'),
    'H': document.getElementById('buttonH'),
    'J': document.getElementById('buttonJ'),
    'K': document.getElementById('buttonK'),
    'L': document.getElementById('buttonL'),
    'Z': document.getElementById('buttonZ'),
    'X': document.getElementById('buttonX'),
    'C': document.getElementById('buttonC'),
    'V': document.getElementById('buttonV'),
    'B': document.getElementById('buttonB'),
    'N': document.getElementById('buttonN'),
    'M': document.getElementById('buttonM'),
    'BACKSPACE': document.getElementById('buttonBackspace'),
    'ENTER': document.getElementById('buttonEnter'),

}

// Function to simulate a button click
function simulateButtonClick(button) {
    const originalBackgroundColor = button.style.backgroundColor;
    const originalStyleColor = button.style.color;
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    button.style.color = 'white';

    setTimeout(() => {
        button.style.backgroundColor = originalBackgroundColor;
        button.style.color = originalStyleColor
    }, 200);
}


document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    const key = event.key.toUpperCase();

    if (buttonMap[key]) {
        simulateButtonClick(buttonMap[key]);
    }
});
```

I looked for the answer but didn't find anything helpful

Comment: The button doesn't seem to contain any inline styles by default. Check the stored values, and use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead of `style` when retrieving the values to store. Or ... rather mark the styles empty when restoring.